# MVC 5 Save Drafts While Ignoring Missing Required Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, required

I have searched for current solutions, but can't find a set of guidelines or examples as to how to achieve the following:

The original requirements involved models with required fields, so we included annotations to those fields.   As usual, there is a last-minute change and we are being asked to allow the users to save drafts.  These drafts must allow the user to save the forms without any of the required fields.

I would like to know what the best practices for this problem are.

Solutions I am considering, but I accept they might be a hack (and that's why I am asking the experts)

1. If the user clicks "Save as Draft" I can capture the fields that have information in another `ActionResult` and run basic validation on those fields.  Since there is a chance that required fields are missing, I am thinking in storing the captured info in a temporal model (without any required annotations).  If the user decides to edit such form, I can populate fields in the view with the temp. model until the user clicks on "Submit"
2. Another option is to remove all required annotations and run client-side validations... but am wondering on the amount of work required to do so.

Any thoughts are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have 2 save methods. 1 which is called from the autosave and 1 that is used to submit the process. In the autosave method **do not check** `if(ModelState.IsValid)`.

Whether you choose to save the incomplete objects to the same table or a different table is your choice. In a relational world I would likely use a separate table, in a non-relational world I would use a singular object collection.

This will allow you to keep the same set of original models. There is a very high cost to duplicating your models, there are certainly times that warrants pass by value/copy but make sure the cost of mapping is there. In this situtation I do not believe there is value in mapping, except perhaps at the persistence level if you need to map to a different object because of an ORM's constraints.

There is deep value in these partial forms. Recording this on the server will allow you to apply analytics to learn why your users abandon your processes. It also gives you the ability to follow up on users who leave incomplete forms such as sending a reminder (nag) email.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to save anything to your database until it is complete. Having a duplicate table where everything is nullable is cludgy as hell. Before HTML5, the typical path was to save the information to the session, which you could then pull from to refill the fields, but that's requires having a session with a relatively high expiry to be useful.

Thankfully, HTML5 has local storage, which is really the best way to handle this now. You just watch for onchange events on your fields and then insert that value into local storage. If the user submits the form successfully, you destroy the local storage values. Otherwise, you attempt to read those values from local storage when the page loads and refill the fields.

See: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

There's pretty broad support, so unless you need to worry about IE6 or IE7, you won't have any issues.

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer, these partial answer surveys are deeply meaningful business information. You need this information on the server to be able to analyze why users aren't completing forms. There is always abandonment. To leave this purely in browser prevents that information from surfacing.

Comment: If there's a compelling business case, then perhaps. But, the OP didn't convey such a scenario. For all we know, this is for an admin portal, in which case abandonment means nothing.

Comment: Autosave implies user experience is a paramount concern. If UX is of concern there is immense business value surrounding users' actions. Businesses don't tend to care about the UX of admin tools (unless they're in the business of selling admin tools).

Comment: That is a highly jaded view. As a developer, I take just as much care and concern with internal applications as external. A user is a user, and just because they work for the same company as me doesn't me they deserve a crappier experience. Nevertheless, even for non-internal applications not all partial forms are meaningful. You're applying blanket logic to something that is very much shades of grey.

Comment: Yes, I'll take consistency over mish-mash. If you're going to do autosave it is far better to have 1 way to do it as opposed to this page is in browser, this page is on server, this page uses post it notes.

Comment: Who says you have to mish-mash? You can use local storage for everything, even if you persist the data as well. The thing is, unless your user is logged in, such that you have a way to actually tie that data to them personally, then persisting it in a database doesn't buy you anything from a save-this-so-I-can-finish-later standpoint. You can run whatever metrics on it you like, but if you want the user to be able to continue filling it out later in a universal way, there's nothing better than local storage.

Comment: I'm not going to spin this about finger printing users even if they're anonymous visitors even potentially first time visitors, but if you have 50 questions and you see 40% of users never complete questions 30-50, something really wrong occurs in the preceding questions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (depending on your data obviously) would be to comply with the database but not the model. By this I mean ignore Model.isValid and disable Javascript validation on the front end but then satisfy the database table. In a form, you mostly have:

- textboxes - default to "" or " "
- checkboxes - easy true/false default
- radio buttons - one is probably already selected
- dates - default to DateTime.MinValue (or DateTimeUTC)
- enums - default to 0 (usually for 'unspecified')

Hopefully you are also saving a flag designating that it is in Draft state so that you know you need to interpret the 'null codes' you have set when it comes to displaying the semi-populated form again.